# How can I add an image, using PDFBox 2.0.1, to a PDF Form?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I've made the PDF Form in LibreOffice writer, and can open it within PDFBox. However, when I list all the acroForm fields, it does not show any of my [image controls](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/More_Controls#Image_Control). Here's how I'm listing my controls:

```
            PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(template);
            PDDocumentCatalog documentCatalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
            PDAcroForm acroForm = documentCatalog.getAcroForm();
            List fields = acroForm.getFields();
            for(PDField p: fields)
            {
                System.out.println(p.getFullyQualifiedName());
            }
```

This lists the 39 fields text fields in the form, but none of the 5 image controls. Are these image controls not being exported to the PDF? Or can PDFBox not access these fields? If it can't be done this way, is there any way I can add a form control that can be set to an image through PDFBox? Buttons are of limited use since I can't set them as 'flat' looking in LibreOffice.

Comment: Could you provide a sample PDF to take a look?

Comment: @MaruanSahyoun, here's a link to the template I'm using - https://www.dropbox.com/s/igv5ngjj44t52xa/APLPortrait.pdf?dl=0

Comment: @MaruanSahyoun, additionally, here's the original odt file that I exported to make the PDF - https://www.dropbox.com/s/e82s2ndominayna/APLPortrait.odt?dl=0

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the image controls (as well as image buttons) are not resulting in a PDF button field. You'd need to use a regular button which is exported.